# Missing CascadeType.LOCK, CascadeType.REPLICATE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE in cascadetypes

Tags: hibernate

I am not able to find CascadeType.LOCK, CascadeType.REPLICATE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE in Hibernate Cascade Types () .

Here is my pom.xml . Any suggestion please ?

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that [`javax.persistence.CascadeType`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.0/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) does not have constants other than ones shown on screenshot.

If target method takes [`org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html) as arguments, then issue is simply that wrong class is imported. If the method takes `javax.persistence.CascadeType` as argument, then choice is limited to constants shown in screenshot.

Comment: .Thanks for the reply .I am also importing javax.persistence.CascadeType class only . In this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types , they have explained about CascadeType.LOCK, CascadeType.REPLICATE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE . I just wanted to try all  type of cascades , and they also provided the code in github . How can I include  CascadeType.LOCK,REPLICATE,SAVE_UPDATE in my code  ?

Comment: If target method takes javax.persistence.CascadeType as argument, you cannot include constants from some unrelated class (even that simple name of class is same). If target method/assignment takes org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType as argument, then one should import that one only.

Comment: Mikko . In the example specified in Baledung.com cascade type is embedded inside onetomany annotation @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) . But I found another way to specify cascade type . This works for me. @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person") @Cascade({CascadeType.LOCK,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH}) where @cascade belongs to org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade package .